# Asp.net core identity Logging in each time a user visits the site?

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an asp.net core app with identity authentication, and I need the user to log in each time they visit the site, so how could I do so?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot track if the user has closed its browser. All you can do is set a sliding interval that is very low. You will log the user out if it hasn't made any requests within that sliding interval.

In your startup/program you need to add to the cookie options something like

```
ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
SlidingExpiration = true,
```

Do be careful, because if the user has the webpage open, but has been inactive for (in this case 5 minutes) he will need to log back in. This might bring some user experience issues.